# Reading table data in generic way in Spring Data JPA

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I know that we can have multiple endpoints to read multiple tables

ex:-

```
 controller "/books", repository<Book,ID>, entity Book

 controller "/invoices" repository<Invoice,ID>, entity Invoice
```

But right now I'm looking for a way to read above entities from one single endpoint given that there maybe future tables.
ex:-

```
controller "/readentity/{entity_name(book,invoice etc)}"
```

I do not need to filter the data and it's just a full read of each table and can forget about dependencies between other tables. Don't know even if this is possible just by with Data JPA. Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The way I did this was adding a generic repository interface like:

```
public interface TableReadService<T> 
{
    List<T> readTableData(String tableName) throws ClassNotFoundException;
}
```

and then an implementation like:

```
private final RepositoryFactorySupport factory;

public  TableReadServiceImpl(EntityManager em) {
    factory = new JpaRepositoryFactory(em);
}

@Override
public List<T> readTableData(String tableName) throws ClassNotFoundException 
{
    JpaRepository repo = (JpaRepository) factory.getRepository(Class.forName("respoitory_package_path."+tableName+"Repository"));
    return repo.findAll();
}
```

finally in the controller:

```
@Autowired
private TableReadServiceImpl<T> tableReadService;

@GetMapping("/{tn}")
public ResponseEntity<List<T>> readTable(@PathVariable String tn) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(tableReadService.readTableData(tn));
}
```

There will be class cast exceptions, so be sure by program you stick to a package which has all repositories. If you have other packages, then you will need a mapping mechanism for packages to repo names via a json file etc